# JQuery: fadeToggle() works in a wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkboxes with id

> 'check1' , 'check2'

two table columns with class

> 'column1', 'column2'

.

In js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.column1').hide();
    $('.column2').hide();


    $('#check1').change(function() {
        $('.column1').fadeToggle();
    });

    $('#check2').change(function() {
        $('.column2').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

When check1 is checked column shows, then hides when unchecked.
The problem is when check2 is checked column hides, and show when unchecked.

They are code in the same way but works in different way.
What causes the problem, how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: is one defaulted to checked and the other unchecked

Comment: @JaromandaX They are all default unchecked.

Comment: then your code works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/4k6ghuLm/

Comment: .column2 may be visible by inline css rule.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal what does inline css rule like? I am not sure whether this situation happens in my code

Comment: Check in your html markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this alternative:

```
$('#check2').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.column2').fadeIn('slow');

    } else {
        $('.column2').fadeOut('slow');   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Could you imagine what causes the problem?

Comment: Since you've not add HTML in your question, I can't explain what wrong with your situation.